# How do I move all files that are not copies in two directories into a third?

Tags: bash

So, I have two directories, both of which have no subdirectories and are filled only with text files. In one directory, "total", all of the text files are present. In a second directory, "processed", only a small subset of those in "total" are present. I need a third directory, "left_to_process", that contains those files in total not in processed. How can I do that? Unfortunately, we're talking about thousands of files so doing this by hand is not recommended...

Comment: I promise it isn't, or are you suggesting I should just google it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work better:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Collate directory of files to parcel out those already processed.
#
#
Wild_Card="*"

  # Iterate over the wildcard set.
  cd total
  for fname in $Wild_Card
  do
    # Ensure we have at least one matching file, as in we did not get back the wildcard string.
    if [ "$fname" == "$Wild_Card" ]
    then
      echo No files found.
      exit 0
    fi

    # If this file name is not processed, make a copy in the left_to_process directory.
    if [ ! -f ../processed/"$fname" ]
    then
      cp ./"$fname" ../left_to_process/"$fname"
      echo "$fname"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

It's easy, simply (assuming no blanks or funnys in filenames):

```
cd total
for i in * ; do 
  if [[ \! -f ../processed/$i ]] ; then
     echo "$i"
  fi
done | \
  xargs -r mv -t ../left_to_process
```

You'll probably have to fix the directories.

Comment: The only "funny" that would cause problems is the newline character I think - I'd probably do something more like `for f in total/*; do [[ -f processed/${f##*/} ]] || printf '%s\0' "$f"; done | xargs -r0 cp -t left_to_process/` which would handle even that edge case

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it...

Because my understanding is that you want to calculate:

> A (total directory files) - B (processed directory files) = C (left to process files)

You could create a new directory, C, and then symbolically link all the files from A into C. Next, for each file in B, execute a rm command on the links in C. What's left will be the files you need to process.

E.g. (using A, B, C as defined above)

```
mkdir C
cd C
ln -s ../A/* ./
for i in ../B/*
do rm `basename "$i"`
done
```

Just `ls` the C directory to see what's left.